# How to Optimize SQL Query to fetch more than 100K rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql

I am writing simple query to Export Test cases with design steps from HP QC. I am getting error for records having more than 70K rows.

[image: Error while fetching more than 70K rows]

Comment: The answer is clearly in your question - contact your "site administrator" and asked them to increase the limit.

Comment: Do two queries: one for the top 50k rows and another for the bottom 50k rows. I would sort by ascending order to get the top 50k, then sort by descending order and get the top 50k rows. This should give you your 100k rows.